# Safari webkitSpeechRecognition continuous bug

Tags: safari, webkitspeechrecognition

I am trying to use webkitSpeechRecognition with the continuous setting set to false (when the user stops speaking, webkitSpeechRecognition auto stops) but when I stop speaking and the webkitSpeechRecognition stops, when using Safari iOS and macOS still show that the microphone is still listening. If I manually start it and stop it, I don't have this problem.

In order to get Safari to recognize that the microphone is no longer listening, I have to start and manually stop webkitSpeechRecognition again.

**EDIT:** The microphone is actually listening and inputting text even after the `.onend` event occurs. Essentially Safari is not actually ending on `.onspeechend` - am I doing something wrong or is this a bug? It only occurs on Safari, not Chrome. Please see example, text will still be inputted even after it says stopped.

[image: Even with Safari minimized]

[image: Real time]

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a workaround to this?

```js
    let speechrecognition;
    if ("webkitSpeechRecognition" in window) {

        // set microphone to show
        speechrecognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();

        // stop listening after the user stops speaking or it can keep listening until the user stops
        speechrecognition.continuous = false; 

        // interim results along with the final results
        speechrecognition.interimResults = true; 
    
    
    speechrecognition.onstart = () => {
      console.log ("started");
        };


        speechrecognition.onend = () => {
            console.log ("stopped");
            
        };


        let final_transcript = "";
        speechrecognition.onresult = (event) => {
            // Create the interim transcript string locally because we don't want it to persist like final transcript
            let interim_transcript = "";

            // Loop through the results from the speech recognition object.
            for (let i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; ++i) {

                if (event.results[i].isFinal) {
                    final_transcript += event.results[i][0].transcript;

                    document.getElementsByClassName("dict")[0].innerHTML = final_transcript;

                } else {
                    interim_transcript += event.results[i][0].transcript;

                    document.getElementsByClassName("dict")[0].innerHTML = interim_transcript;
                }
            }

            final_transcript = "";

        };
    }
```

```html
 
 
 <div class="dict"></div>
 
 <button onclick="speechrecognition.start();">start</button>
 
  <button onclick="speechrecognition.stop();">stop</button>
```

Comment: Here is my work around:

recognition.onspeechend = () => {
 if (navigator.vendor.indexOf('Apple') > -1){
  recognition.start();
  recognition.stop();
 }
};

It seems to work but still gives an error in Safari's console. Better than nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought it would be worth making OP's comment on his own question into an answer, since it also worked for me. I was finding that calling `recognition.stop()` successfully caused the `onend()` callback to fire, but then the service continued listening regardless (this is on Safari for iOS 16.1.1).

The practice of redundantly calling `start()` right before you call `stop()` seems to be the key to working around this, regardless of whether it's in an `onspeechend()` callback or elsewhere.

```
function SeriouslyStopListening(recognition)
{
    if (navigator.vendor.indexOf('Apple') > -1)
    {
        try{ recognition.start(); }
        catch(err) { }
    }
    recognition.stop();
}
```

Comment: Prettay, prettay, prettay good. Pretty good.